# Why Same Closure type does not get assigned

Tags: ios, swift, closures, variable-types

```
class ParentClass<T>
{
    var success : ((T)->Void)?
}

extension ParentClass
{
   func success<T>(success: ((T) -> Void)?) -> ParentClass where T : Codable
   {
        self.success = success
        return self
    }
}
```

here I just tried to assign the parameter value to parent class variable but it throw this error 
Cannot assign value of type `'((T) -> Void)?' to type '((T) -> Void)?'`

Also when I go for suggestion prompt, again again it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the **Generic**  type you used in the class (and for the variable) definition is **NOT** same with the Generic  you defined in the function signature. You should make sure both are same:

```
class ParentClass<T> {    
    var success : ((T)->Void)?
}

extension ParentClass {
   func success(success: ((T) -> Void)?) -> ParentClass {
        self.success = success
        return self
    }
}
```

And if you want it to be codable:

```
class ParentClass<T: Codable> { ,,, }
```

Or in the extension:

```
extension ParentClass where T: Codable { ,,, }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func success<T>(success: ((T) -> Void)?) -> ParentClass where T : Codable
```

The `<T>` here is shadowing the `T` in ParentClass. It's the same as if you had a local `var` with the same name as a property. Just remove it, and the shadowing will go away:

```
extension ParentClass where T: Codable {
    func success(success: ((T) -> Void)?) -> ParentClass
}
```

Note that this only adds this method when `T` happens to be Codable. There's no requirement here that `T` always be Codable. If you always need that, then you should define `ParentClass<T: Codable>` (and remove the `where` clause).

(Thanks to Mojtaba for reminding me that the `where` has to go on the extension here, not the function.)

Comment: 'where' clause cannot be attached to a non-generic declaration